# Php can not upload file out of /var/www/html even after disabling Selinux

Tags: php, apache, selinux

OS: RHEL 9 with php 8.3 and httpd.
Selinux disabled.
Php Application is hosted in `/var/www/html/application`. Trying to upload file to `/home/user/uploads`.
This error showing:

```
move_uploaded_file(/home/user/uploads/become_a_student_inline.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

ls -Z Shows:

```
$ ls -Z
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 uploads
```

ls -l Shows:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 4 ec2-user apache 35 Mar 27 10:17 uploads
```

Comment: I did reboot. not working

Comment: safe_mode is set to Off and open_basedir is commented. Not working

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Could not use `home` directory. Created `uploads` in `root` directory and changed permissions accordingly.

Comment: If I were you I will upload to say /var/www/html/application/uploads , and then create symbolic links in home/user/uploads to point to that folder

Comment: This is a client requirement. They dont want to keep their uploaded files inside application. Thats why I am uploading outside and keeping symlink.

Comment: Your clients have it backwards.  Upload to a location within your Apache DocumentRoot, then some other process reads the file, validates it, if it is secure, then copy it "inside" your infrastructure.  Don't save directly "inside", use a security validation process.